# Selecting an element from a matrix in a cell

Tags: matlab

Good day,

I have got something similar as:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
B = [2 3; 4 5; 6 7];
C{1} = A; 
C{2} = B;
clear A;
clear B;
```

Now I would like to select element (2,1) from matrix B, that is, element (2,1) from C{2}. However, matrix B itself does not exist any more.

One possibility is:

```
B = C{2};
B(2,1)
```

However, is there a more direct way to access elements from matrices which are stored in a cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cells allow you to chain subscripts in the following manner

```
>> C{2}(2, 1)

ans =

     4
```